# Errors porting Ubuntu touch to the Galaxy A10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

Hey I've been trying to port Ubuntu touch to the A10 following the official guide located [here](http://docs.halium.org/en/latest/porting/get-sources.html).  I've found the device repository for the a10 [here](https://github.com/geckyn/android_device_samsung_a10), and vendor blobs [here](https://github.com/geckyn/proprietary_vendor_samsung_a10). So the XML manifest file I ended up with is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
        <remote name="a10_remote" fetch = "https://github.com/geckyn" revision="lineage-16.0"/>
        <project path="device/samsung/a10" name="android_device_samsung_a10" remote="a10_remote"/>
        <project path="kernel/samsung/a10" name="android_kernel_samsung_exynos7885" remote="a10_remote"/>
        <project path = "vendor/samsung/a10" name="proprietary_vendor_samsung_a10" remote="a10_remote"/>
</manifest>
```

The `./halium/devices/setup a10` command exits with no errors. But then when I run `breakfast a10`, I get the following output:

```
build/core/product_config.mk:249: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "lineage_a10".  Stop.
build/core/product_config.mk:249: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "cm_a10".  Stop.
build/core/product_config.mk:249: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "lineage_a10". Stop.
Device a10 not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from LineageOS Github http://github.com/LineageOS.
Repository for a10 not found in the LineageOS Github repository list. If this is in error, you may need to manually add it to your lo
cal_manifests/roomservice.xml.
build/core/product_config.mk:249: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "lineage_a10". Stop.
build/core/product_config.mk:249: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "lineage_a10". Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'lineage_a10'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

The A10 doesn't have an official Lineage OS port, in my knowledge, so I understand that there would be no reference to it on Lineage's GitHub. And I don't mention this repository in my manifest. Why do I get this error then?

These errors above were generated when using Halium 7.1 with unofficial Lineage OS 16.0 sources, because the A10 shipped with Android 9. I tried to use this command:

```
repo init -u https://github.com/Halium/android -b halium-9.0 --depth=1
```

instead to match the Hallium version with the Lineage OS version. However, I can't find the `Halium` directory mentioned in the docs when executing the command for this version of Halium. How can I find a work around for this issue?

The A10 is a project Treble enabled device, so would the GSI be the only way to get Ubuntu touch working?

Comment: While your inquiry is an example of a "good question", AskUbuntu doesn't provide support for Ubuntu Touch. Instead, you might want to ask your question over at [the UBports Forum](https://forums.ubports.com), as they have taken on the responsibility of developing and maintaining the project 

Comment: Alright I'll take this down and repost over there. I just saw a couple of "accepted" questions here regarding Ubuntu Touch and didn't know the UBports forum existed.